# Spark-shell meaning of displayed Number on Stage

Tags: apache-spark

```
[Stage 5:=====>  (26372 + 264) / 27840] 

[stage 6:=========> (0 + 200 ) / 200 ]
```

Hi, I'm using spark 1.6.1.

I use spark-shell to see the data and i want to know the meaning of each number here.

```
( A + B / C )
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The meaning of `[Stage 5:=====> (26372 + 264) / 27840]` is

```
(numCompletedTasks + numActiveTasks) / totalNumOfTasksInThisStage)
```

- Number of Completed Tasks = 26372
- Number of Active Tasks = 264
- Total number of tasks in this stages = 27840

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. I want add one more question! Is Number of Active Tasks related to number of worker nodes? How can I increase the numActiveTasks to speed up?

Comment: No. Number of tasks is a sum of all partitions per every stage in a job.